# JQuery: Bind click on hrefs

Tags: jquery, onclick, href, replace

I'm trying to replace my hrefs links by JQuery click events: for that I have placed a insite class on every  concerned.

This is the code I have placed at the bottom of my page:

```
$('.insite').each(function(i,a) {
    $('this').click(function() {
        $('#content').load(a.attr('href')+' #content');
    });
});
```

Did I forget anything?

Thanks

Comment: Should be $(this) instead of $('this').

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.insite').click(function(ev) {
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

You don't need the each.
And the ev.preventDefault is needed so it doesn't load the href in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the jQuery library? Also, is your code wrapped in a DOM-ready event?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(function() {
   $('.insite').click(function(e) {
     $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.insite').click(function(){
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the each. You can just do:

```
$('.insite').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do stuff
});
```

No idea what you are trying to do with `$('#content').load(a.attr('href')+' #content');`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$(this)
```

instead of

```
$('this')
```